# User/Passwords - Changing it when original not known

Tags: facebook, facebook-application

One of my clients found a very old facebook page for their organization (6/2009), and the person who maintained it is no longer around.

How would she get it deleted or find out user/password to get it updated?  Any suggestion greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your best chance is to contact the person who set it up or report the site as a forgery